# Issue with uploading files from local directory to aws S3 using python 2.7 and boto 2

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto

I’m doing simple operation to of downloading the gzip files from S3 bucket to the local directory. I’m extracting those into another local directory and then uploading them back to S3 bucket again into archive folder path. While doing this operation I want to make sure I am processing same set of files that I initially download from S3 bucket which is (f_name) in below code. Now, below code is not uploading those back to S3 , that’s where I’m stuck. But able to download from S3 and extract it into local directory. Can you please help me understand what is wrong with the _uploadFile function?

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import *
import os
import os.path
aws_bucket= "event-logs-dev”  ## S3 Bucket name
local_download_directory= "/Users/TargetData/Download/test_queue1/“ ## local                directory to download the gzip files from S3.
Target_directory_to_extract = "/Users/TargetData/unzip”  ##local directory to gunzip the downloaded files.
Target_s3_path_to_upload= "event-logs-dev/data/clean/xact/logs/archive/“   ## S3 bucket path to upload the files.

def decompressAllFilesFromNetfiler(self,aws_bucket,local_download_directory,Target_d irectory_to_extract,Target_s3_path_to_upload):
zipFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(local_download_directory) if re.match(r'.*\.tar\.gz', f)]
for f_name in zipFiles:
    if os.path.exists(Target_directory_to_extract+"/"+f_name[:-len('.tar.gz')]) and os.access(Target_directory_to_extract+"/"+f_name[:-len('.tar.gz')], os.R_OK):
        print ('File {} already exists!'.format(f_name))
    else:
        f_name_with_path = os.path.join(local_download_directory, f_name)
        os.system('mkdir -p {} && tar vxzf {} -C {}'.format(Target_directory_to_extract, f_name_with_path, Target_directory_to_extract))
        print ('Extracted file {}'.format(f_name))
        self._uploadFile(aws_bucket,f_name,Target_s3_path_to_upload,Target_directory_to_extract)

def _uploadFile(self, aws_bucket, f_name,Target_s3_path_to_upload,Target_directory_to_extract):
full_key_name = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(Target_s3_path_to_upload, f_name))
path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(Target_directory_to_extract, f_name))
try:
    print "Uploaded extracted file to: %s" % (full_key_name)
    key = aws_bucket.new_key(full_key_name)
    key.set_contents_from_filename(path)
except:
    if full_key_name is None:
        print "Error uploading”
```

Currently, the output prints that `Uploaded extracted file to: event-logs-dev/data/clean/xact/logs/archive/1442235602129200000.tar.gz`, but nothing is uploaded to S3 bucket. Your help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have cut and pasted parts of your code  - and maybe formatting was lost as your code above will not work as pasted.   I've taken the liberty to make it PEP8 (mostly) however there is still some missing code to create the S3 objects.   Since your import the modules, I presume that you have that section of code and just didn't paste it.

here is a cleaned up version of your code formatted correctly.   I also added a Exception code to your try: block to print out the error you get.  You should update the Exception to be more specific to the Exceptions thrown for make_key or set_contents_... but the general Exception will get you started.  If nothing more this is more readable, but you should include your S3 connection code too  - and remove anything that is specific to your domain (e.g. keys, trade secrets, etc).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
do some download
some extract
and some upload
"""

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import *
import os
import os.path


aws_bucket = 'event-logs-dev'
local_download_directory = '/Users/TargetData/Download/test_queue1/'
Target_directory_to_extract = '/Users/TargetData/unzip'
Target_s3_path_to_upload = 'event-logs-dev/data/clean/xact/logs/archive/'

'''
MUST BE SOME MAGIC HERE TO GET  AN S3 CONNECTION ???
aws_bucket IS NOT A BUCKET OBJECT ...
'''


def decompressAllFilesFromNetfiler(self,
                                   aws_bucket,
                                   local_download_directory,
                                   Target_directory_to_extract,
                                   Target_s3_path_to_upload):
    '''
    decompress stuff
    '''
    zipFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(
        local_download_directory) if re.match(r'.*\.tar\.gz', f)]
    for f_name in zipFiles:
        if os.path.exists(
            "{}/{}".format(Target_directory_to_extract,
                           f_name[:len('.tar.gz')])) and os.access(
                               "{}/{}".format(Target_directory_to_extract,
                                              f_name[:len('.tar.gz')])) and os.R_OK:

            print ('File {} already exists!'.format(f_name))
        else:
            f_name_with_path = os.path.join(local_download_directory, f_name)
            os.system('mkdir -p {} && tar vxzf {} -C {}'.format(
                Target_directory_to_extract,
                f_name_with_path,
                Target_directory_to_extract))
            print ('Extracted file {}'.format(f_name))
            self._uploadFile(aws_bucket,
                             f_name,
                             Target_s3_path_to_upload,
                             Target_directory_to_extract)


def _uploadFile(self,
                aws_bucket,
                f_name,
                Target_s3_path_to_upload,
                Target_directory_to_extract):
    full_key_name = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(Target_s3_path_to_upload,
                                                    f_name))
    path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(Target_directory_to_extract, f_name))
    try:
        S3CONN = S3Connection()
        BUCKET = S3CONN.get_bucket(aws_bucket)
        key = BUCKET.new_key(full_key_name)
        key.set_contents_from_filename(path)
        print "Uploaded extracted file to: {}".format(full_key_name)
    except Exception as UploadERR:
        if full_key_name is None:
            print 'Error uploading'
        else:
            print "Error : {}".format(UploadERR)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to correct this code. I really appreciate your help. Yes, I already have a code to connect to S3 bucket. I ran your above code and getting below output. So, currently with this code, file extraction is working fine, but it is not uploading these files to S3, also error is triggering. Please advice the next step.                                            `Extracted file 1440190802314590000.tar.gz
Error : 'unicode' object has no attribute 'new_key'
x 144019080590001/V.data
Extracted file 1440190802314590001.tar.gz
Error : 'unicode' object has no attribute 'new_key'`

Comment: This directive is not valid, unless aws_bucket is a bucket object.